The warm sand but hot water
I have been wondering about the difference in the presence or absence of the definite articles in the following sentences.

I lay on the warm sand.
I drank warm water.

Both of them refer to uncountable nouns but somehow we tend to omit the article in the second sentence (according to the examples found on the Internet). Can someone think of a good explanation?

You could say I lay on warm sand, I drank the hot water

Would it affect the meaning?

The warm sand probably refers to a particular patch of sand (maybe the reader knows that the speaker is on the beach).  It would be perfectly possible to say I drank the warm water if the existence of a source of warm water had been previously mentioned.

When I was on holiday last year, the first thing I did was to lie on warm sand and drink  hot water.  Would such uses of warm sand and hot water be possible in this context? After all, I haven't said anything about the beach where the sand was nor about the source of the water yet.

The prior reference could be tangential: "I parked at the usual car park. After scrambling down the steep slope to the beach, I lay on the warm sand.' 'Usual' licenses (by adding identification) the first 'the',  and now the scene is set, the other two definite articles are licensed.

I lay on warm sand. I drank warm water. Both can have "the" or not. It depends on whether you are spouting a generality or being specific in a particular conversational or written context. water and sand in those examples are non-countable. Countable: The blue waters of the Med. The warm sands of the mighty desert.

There is nothing incorrect about "I lay on warm sand" or "I drank the warm water".
The word "the" has its usual meaning, of marking the sand or water as "determined".  By saying "the warm sand" you indicate that the particular bit of warm sand is known to you and the speaker and so is determined.  By omitting "the" you indicate that it is undetermermined.
The reason that "the warm sand" is more common, is that, in context, there is probably a particular beach that the speaker is referring to.  But "warm water" is more common because it is unlikely that there is a particular source of warm water that is relevant to the context.
